# Messing with this in prototype's method

Tags: javascript, prototype

Ok, here's the situation:

```
var vowels = ['a', 'i', 'y', 'e', 'o', 'u'];
String.prototype.isVowel = function () {
  return vowels.indexOf(this) !== -1;
};

alert('a'.isVowel());
```

It will alert 'false' since `this` references not `'a'` but its prototype. To make it work we need to make a little change.

```
String.prototype.isVowel = function () {
  return vowels.indexOf(this[0]) !== -1;
};

alert('a'.isVowel());
```

This will work since `String.prototype` contains all characters of original string. It's a hack actually and I don't like it.

But what do we need to do to make this code work?

```
Number.prototype.is5 = function () { return this === 5; }

alert((5).is5()); //will alert 'false'
```

Or we just don't need to touch prototypes?

Comment: Is 'Y' a vowel, now? In (British) English, I'm fairly sure it's not.

Comment: "y" is sometimes a vowel.

Comment: @DavidThomas Phonemes can be vowels; letter represent phonemees: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10458/when-is-y-a-vowel. Now let's all get back to doing some programming :)

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xuNhrogY-Mo

Comment: @apsillers: yeah, I was just reading that to find out. I'm fascinated that I didn't know, and don't recall ever being taught, this. :)

Comment: you should be using `==` in your number method instead of `===`

Comment: Your assumption is false. `this` doesn't refer to the prototype. It simply refers to a string **object** not a string **primitive**.

Comment: Also *"This will work since String.prototype contains all characters of original string."* is incorrect. The characters of a string are not stored on the prototype. If it were so, it would imply that every string had the same value, which we know is not true ;) To convince yourself, check the output of `console.dir(new String('foo'));`. Note that the characters are stored on the string object itself, not its prototype.

Comment: @FelixKling I completely agree with the above, but *"The characters of a string are not stored on the prototype. If it were so, it would imply that every string had the same value, which we know is not true ;)"*, two strings with same value refer to the same location in heap.

Comment: @Givi: I only wanted to point out that properties of the prototype are shared and hence if something changes the prototype, all instances are affected. So, if the actual value of a string was stored on the prototype, then every string instance would have the same value. Or put it differently: There could always only be one string value, the value of the last instantiated string (it would "overwrite" the value of the previous string). Does that make sense? It's more of a though experiment than a technical explanation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is what is called *boxing*. If you have a primitive value and then call a method on that value, it will be wrapped as an object of the type `String`, `Number`, `Boolean`, or what have you. This is equivalent to calling `new String('a')`, for instance. (It is documented in [the ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.3).)

`new String('a')` is not the same as `'a'`. It therefore is not found in the array.

What you need to do, therefore, is convert the value back into the primitive value. You can always accomplish this with the `valueOf` method:

```
return vowels.indexOf(this.valueOf()) !== -1;
```

Your method is to call `this[0]`. This works, because it gets the first character from the string as a primitive, which is then found in the string. The downside is that `ab` would also be considered a vowel by this method.

---

Similarly with numbers:

```
 Number.prototype.is5 = function () { return this.valueOf() === 5; };
```

---

One other point: this is the default behaviour of Javascript. It is not obvious or intuitive, as you have shown. In ECMAScript 5, "strict mode" was created, where all kinds of undesirable behaviours are disabled. Auto-boxing is one of them. So, if you use a modern browser, this will have the expected behaviour:

```
Number.prototype.is5 = function () {
    "use strict";
    return this === 5;
};
```

Comment: Right. Hence the statement in the question,  *"It will alert 'false' since this references not 'a' but its prototype."*, is incorrect.

Comment: Btw, it's equivalent to calling `new String('a')`. `String('a')` will return a primitive.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the way you declared `String.prototype.isVowel`, which worked acceptably.  Now look at `Number.prototipe.is5()`.  See the differences?

- prototipe is misspelled, and should be prototype.
- is5() shouldn't have () after it.

That leaves you with this:

```
Number.prototype.is5 = //...
```

You should've gotten an error when setting Number.prototipe.is5(), so maybe these are all just typos in posting.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I fixed my mistakes, but I still have a point in my question. Yet it is not quite correct